# How to get a certain info from a json format?

Tags: json

I am trying to get the count number of occurrenceTypeId = "DANGEROUS_ATTACK_AWAY". For example in this case i want to display 10. I mention that this properties and valus aren't in the same order all the time, so liveStatistics[3].count is not working.

```
  "liveStatistics": [
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "SHOTS_OFF_TARGET_AWAY",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "SHOTS_ON_TARGET_AWAY",
                    "count": 2
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "CORNERS_HOME",
                    "count": 5
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "DANGEROUS_ATTACK_AWAY",
                    "count": 10
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "CORNERS_AWAY",
                    "count": 3
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "SHOTS_OFF_TARGET_HOME",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "ATTACK_HOME",
                    "count": 35
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "DANGEROUS_ATTACK_HOME",
                    "count": 18
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "GOALS_HOME",
                    "count": 2
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "SHOTS_ON_TARGET_HOME",
                    "count": 6
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "ATTACK_AWAY",
                    "count": 22
                }
            ]
```

Comment: With which language are you processing the JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const liveStatistics = [
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "SHOTS_OFF_TARGET_AWAY",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "SHOTS_ON_TARGET_AWAY",
                    "count": 2
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "CORNERS_HOME",
                    "count": 5
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "DANGEROUS_ATTACK_AWAY",
                    "count": 10
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "CORNERS_AWAY",
                    "count": 3
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "SHOTS_OFF_TARGET_HOME",
                    "count": 1
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "ATTACK_HOME",
                    "count": 35
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "DANGEROUS_ATTACK_HOME",
                    "count": 18
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "GOALS_HOME",
                    "count": 2
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "SHOTS_ON_TARGET_HOME",
                    "count": 6
                },
                {
                    "occurrenceTypeId": "ATTACK_AWAY",
                    "count": 22
                }
            ];


const getCount = (occurenceTypeId) => {
    const item = liveStatistics.find(el => el.occurrenceTypeId === occurenceTypeId);
    if (!item) {
      console.log(`No count found for occurence type id ${occurenceTypeId}`);
      return;
   }
   console.log(item.count)
   return item.count;
};

getCount('DANGEROUS_ATTACK_HOME');
getCount('ATTACK_AWAY');
getCount('RANDOM');
getCount('SHOTS_ON_TARGET_HOME');
```

You have to do a `.find()` on that array to get the desired object.